# Two Intents that start the same class, getExtras() cause IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, indexoutofboundsexception

I need to start one Activity (say **WriteAtivity**), twice, but in different mode.
In MainActivity what happens.

For example:

```
addNote.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent writeAct = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WriteActivity
            // HERE, I DO NOT NEED OF putExtra()
            startActivity(writeAct);
        }
    });
```

and

```
editNote.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent visualizza = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WriteActivity.class);
                // HERE INSTEAD I HAVE NEED OF putExtra()
                visualizza.putExtra("posizione", position);
                startActivity(visualizza);
            }
        });
```

and in **onCreate()** of **WriteActivity**

```
intent = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("posizione");
rifTitleNote.setText(listNote.get(posizione).getTitle());
```

As you can see, in **one** i do not need putExtra() and in **second** I do.

I do this because I use the WriteActivity, at first, for *write a note*, and then, for *edit the note*.
This, in any case causes **IndexOutOfBoundsException**: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Do you know how I can overcome this problem?
Or give me advice on how to do this?
Thanks! :D

Comment: Please show us the code

Comment: share logcat to give a idea where problem is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `getIntExtra()` with a default value, and make sure that the value is not set to the default value before using it.

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();    
int posizione = intent.getIntExtra("posizione", -1);
if (posizione  != -1){
 rifTitleNote.setText(listNote.get(posizione).getTitle());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the existence of the extra and handle accordingly if it exists or not. See [Android's Intent documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) for [hasExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#hasExtra(java.lang.String)).

```
if (getIntent().hasExtra("posizione")) {
    // Do stuff with extra
}
```

You could also set an action on the Intent that indicates how the Activity should handle the incoming intent. This is probably the "better" approach but might be overkill depending on your project.